# Pandas calculating a new column under condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

Here is my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-01-01 12:00:00','2020-01-01 15:00:00','2020-01-06 07:00:00','2020-01-15 13:00:00','2020-01-22 12:00:00'],
                    'numb_total':[8,25,11,14,8]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

gives me:

```
                   date numb_total
0   2020-01-01 12:00:00          8
1   2020-01-01 15:00:00         25
2   2020-01-06 07:00:00         11
3   2020-01-15 13:00:00         14
4   2020-01-22 12:00:00          8
```

Now i want to add a new column, that gives me the `numb_total * x` (`x=5`) under special conditions, else `*y` (`y=10`).

The condition:
If `date` is a "Monday" or "Tuesday" and `time` of date is between 08:00 - 14:00:

```
df['numb_new'] = df['numb_total']*x
```

else:

```
df['numb_new'] = df['numb_total']*y
```

To get the `day_name` and the `time` i did this:

```
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day_name()
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time
```

How can i create this new column `df['numb_new']` efficent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-01-01 12:00:00', '2020-01-01 15:00:00', '2020-01-06 07:00:00',
                            '2020-01-15 13:00:00', '2020-01-22 12:00:00'],
                   'numb_total': [8, 25, 11, 14, 8]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

hour_mask = (8 <= df['date'].dt.hour) & (df['date'].dt.hour <= 14)

# for weekday Monday is 0 and Tuesday 1
day_mask = np.isin(df['date'].dt.weekday, [0, 1])

df['numb_new'] = df['numb_total'] * np.where(hour_mask & day_mask,  5, 10)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                 date  numb_total  numb_new
0 2020-01-01 12:00:00           8        80
1 2020-01-01 15:00:00          25       250
2 2020-01-06 07:00:00          11       110
3 2020-01-15 13:00:00          14       140
4 2020-01-22 12:00:00           8        80
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def create_col(date_col,value_col,x,y,min_hour,max_hour,days):
   #assert that a column is datatime
   assert ptypes.is_datetime64_any_dtype(date_col)
   #initiate the condition of hours
   hour_cond = (min_hour <= date_col.dt.hour) & (date_col.dt.hour <= max_hour)
   #initiate the condition of days
   day_mask = np.isin(date_col.dt.weekday, days)
   #return the condionned array 
   return value_col * np.where(hour_cond & day_mask,  x, y)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-01-01 12:00:00', '2020-01-01 15:00:00',
'2020-01-06 07:00:00','2020-01-15 13:00:00','2020-01-22 12:00:00'],
               'numb_total': [8, 25, 11, 14, 8]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df["numb_new"] = create_col(df['date'] ,df['numb_total'],5,10,8,14,[0,1])
print(df)
```

This is a more generic answer where you can change the output according to the passed parameters.